# entity frame work does not support one-to-one containment

Tags: entity-framework

If a user has multiple locations
And if a user has a single role.
My table design will be like

**TableUser**

```
Userid (pk)
Username
RoleId (fk)
```

**TableRole**

```
RoleId (pk)
RoleName
```

**TableLocation**

```
LocationId (pk)
LocationName
```

**UserLocation**

```
LocationId (fk) (part of composite pk)
Userid (fk)(part of composite pk)
```

I have entity framework 4.0.

When I fetch a user entity the user entity does not have a Role object with it.
But it does have a Location object.
Why is this like this?
Is it the default behavior of entity framework?
Does it support only one-to-many relations by default?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, EF doesn't support one-to-one relation modeled this way. To enforce this relation in the database you must mark `RoleId` in the database with unique index / constraint. EF doesn't support unique keys so it cannot model this relation as one-to-one. The only way to model one-to-one relation in EF is on top of primary keys:

```
Role - PK RoleId
User - PK, FK UserId
```

That means that instead of `User.RoleId` you will use `User.UserId` as FK to `Role`.

If you want to keep your current structure you must make it one-to-many relation (one role can have many users), don't expose `Users` navigation property on the `Role` and place unique key to the database. It will still allow you assigning multiple users to single role in the application but database will fire exception if you try to save it.

Comment: hi Ladislav Mrnka i have edited my post giving pk and fk hope your post is still valid. am i right?

Comment: i am waiting for a third comment over this.